# Being someone's pet

Tags: meaning, expressions

I heard *teacher's pet* in a movie and I know it means that teacher likes a student more than other students.
so I have a few questions:

1. I was wondering if this expression can be applied to other people?
2. Can it be used for adults?

Example: my wife is her mom's pet!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Teachers pet" is a stand-alone idiomatic expression, and I have never heard "pet" used this way with other things.  I suppose it *could* be, but it doesn't sound very clever.

In creative writing, of course, you can metaphorically say someone is a "pet":

> He was her pet, her plaything, something to whistle over when she was lonely and to brush away when she became bored.

but this negative meaning of an *owned animal* is quite different from "teacher's pet", which is usually more positive.

I suppose "teacher's pet" can apply to adults, but it would be weird, with possible sexual overtones.  In this case you would soften the idiom with "**like** a teacher's pet" to diminish any awkward connotations.

Comment: how about the combination of other words with `pet`? like boss's pet etc.

Comment: @AliSherafat  "Boss' pet" is possible, but not really used.  Boss' *favorite* would be the expression with a similar meaning.

Comment: @Ali: Offhand I can only think of ***teacher's pet*** and ***pet project*** for "natural, idiomatic" ***metaphoric*** usages. As Andrew says, if you wanted to extend the usage beyond the literal in any other context you'd probably either explicitly make it a ***simile*** (using, for example, ***like** a pet*), or provide plenty of "spoonfeeding" additional context *(whistle over, brush away)* to ensure the intended sense was crystal clear. But that's more about "creative writing" - probably not very important for the average learner.

Comment: I've heard "boss's pet" used, but I agree it's very rare, and clearly intended to be demeaning. "Teacher's pet" is not a positive thing to call someone either. It's usually used as an insult by children who are not doing well in school against a child who gets along well with the teacher.

Comment: Occasionally someone will say that a person treats his or her spouse or boyfriend/girlfriend like a pet, as in, "Bob treats sally like she's his pet." This is intended to be insulting to the person acting as the pet-owner for demeaning another person, and often to the pet for tolerating such treatment.

Comment: @Jay I agree that "teacher's pet" is often an insult, but it's possible to use it in a more positive way, as if it was endearing, "Oh look, little Bobbie is such a teacher's pet, isn't it cute!"

Answer (score 4):

Another use of **pet** can be heard in parts of northern England.

It is used as an affectionate term of endearment (like saying hello dear).

Here are some examples:

> How are you pet?

( used to refer to someone they know or to a stranger)

> Have a great day pet.

other similar affectionate words used in England are dear, love, me duck etc. and any one of them could work in the sentences above.

Comment: ["Pint of lager please Mary." "Right you are my love!"](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/22dbf5be-b067-4f57-8408-69aa9b6da2ea).  If she said, "Right you are my pet!"  it would probably mean the same thing.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I should also add that pet isn't normally used for men, but I may be wrong.(mainly for women or kids).

Answer (score 2):

Let's start with this.  Per [Merriam-Webster dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pet) the *FIRST* definition of pet is either:

> a) a pampered and usually spoiled child, or
>   b) a person who is treated
>   with unusual kindness or consideration

and the meaning of a *domesticated animal* is only the SECOND definition.

Thus, **teacher's pet** is a person that the teacher treats *with unusual kindness of consideration* (generally because that person is a favorite of the teacher).

Like a teacher, any other person can have a pet:  a boss, a co-worker, a doorman, anyone.

Second, the similar terms **[pet project/theory/subject/etc](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/pet-project-theory-subject)** are well-known and mean:

> a plan, idea, or subject that you particularly like or are interested
>   in

All of these terms are related.  For example, when you say that a student is the *teacher's pet*, it means that that student is a favorite of the teacher. A *pet project* is the same concept:  a pet project is a favorite project of someone.  Similar with *theory, subject* or whatever.  The term always means a favorite.

There is a related term that can be applied to other people and used for some adults.  It is **pet cat**.  It is an example of *coach-speak* and particularly popularized by American football coach Bill Parcells and his staffs.  The [original meaning of the word](http://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/pet_cat_underrated_football_player) as used by Parcells and his coaches is:

> **14 January 2007, *Macon (GA) Telegraph*, Michael A. Lough column:**  “I
>   knew it was a bad sign when Bill Parcells talked about how ‘very, very
>   athletic’ his pet cat, Cody, was earlier in the week. Men should never
>   publicly acknowledge owning a cat.”
>
> **30 March 2007, *Fort Worth (TX) Star-Telegram*, “Trying to eliminate
>   ‘cat’ calls,” pg. D6:**  IRVING — Bill Parcells was a cat guy. He had a
>   big, fat pet cat at his house. And he had his pet cats at Valley
>   Ranch, too. Especially in April. “Pet cats” is a Parcellsism; they
>   were the prospects whom a coach or scout adored. They are often so
>   fond of such prospects they try to make sure their “pet cat” is
>   drafted, regardless what the scouting consensus is. And every coach,
>   general manager or scout has a pet cat; 2004 second-round flop Jacob
>   Rogers was a Parcells’ pet cat.

However, it has [begun to take on a life of it's own](https://www.bloggingtheboys.com/2017/6/15/15804772/dallas-cowboys-2017-roster-which-down-roster-player-is-your-pet-cat-this-year-udfa-rookies-nfl-draft) and is being used on a broader basis:

> Among Cowboys fans, pet cat has since come to refer to a player who is
>   a bubble player (even making the practice squad is often considered
>   pet cat success) and is commonly selected from the very bottom of the
>   roster where you'll find late-round draft picks, undrafted free agents
>   or even street free agents. The pet cat is often - and preferably -
>   chosen without the slightest factual or quantifiable basis. In fact,
>   some would argue that you do not choose your pet cat, your pet cat
>   chooses you.